# What would be an appropriate answer to "Hast noch mehr Eisen im Feuer?" if you want to reply in a similar way?

Tags: word-choice

I do not want to reply in simple sentence and just say "No." or "Nein, ich habe keine Eisen mehr im Feuer.".

I am looking for some related proverb or phrase that could be used instead if the answer would be "No."

Comment: Not really a _"counter idiom"_, but you could respond: _"Nein, aber es sind ja auch keine Pferde mehr im Stall."_

Comment: What are you trying to communicate in your reply? That there *are* "mehr Eisen im Feuer" or that there *are not*? Or do you want to leave this open in your reply?

Comment: in present Scenario i want to communicate "not" but for learning purpose it would be good to know both yes and no replies.

Comment: M.E. ist die Phrase nicht "mehr Eisen im Feuer haben" (5 Kilo, nicht 3) sondern "mehrere Eisen im Feuer haben" - ob das aber aus der Waffen- oder Hufschmiede kommt, oder ganz unspezifisch dem Schmiedewesen, weiß ich nicht. Aber es sind Stücke gemeint die auch unterschiedlich stark glühen können, so dass man das eine schon bearbeiten kann, während das andere noch Zeit braucht.

Answer (score 2):

> ... wondering if there is a Counter Idiom for this question

No, there's no *"counter idiom"*<sup>1</sup> for *Eisen im Feuer haben* despite *Keine Eisen (mehr) im Feuer haben* AFAIK.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Whatever is meant with *counter idiom*.</sub>

Comment: 1) Maybe a reference to Monkey Island?